# Only submit this.val on form when submitted?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm making a form that displays a dynamic value and I have the forms action in a Jquery function and I want to take a value out of `$(this).closest('tr') <input type="text" class="line_Order_ID" value="'.$Order_ID.'" size="5" readonly>` I want to take the value from the `.line_Order_ID` and send it to a php page to process.

***jQuery***

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  $('.viewThis').live({
        click: function() { 

        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var Order_ID = $('.line_Order_ID', $tr).val();

        $('form#ordersList').attr({
            action: "phpDump.php",
            target: "_blank",
        }).submit();

       return false;
    } 
});
});
```

Any ideas??

Comment: easiest way, give the input an ID if you have more than one of the same class. On a side note `live()` is deprecated see here: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 1):

Given that your existing code already seems to get the value from the input in question and put it in the `Order_ID` variable, is your question how to put that value into the form and submit it?

If so, I would think the two most obvious ways would be to put it in a hidden input field or to add it as a query string parameter.

Add this to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenOrderId" name="orderId" />
```

(Use whatever `name` you want - obviously that's the name of the parameter you'll process in your PHP.)

Then in your function just before your existing `.submit()` add:

```
$("#hiddenOrderId").val(Order_Id);
```

(You could also create the hidden input dynamically and then set its value, but since you seem to be targeting a blank window you can presumably submit multiple times and for that case I think creating a single hidden input directly in your html markup is a lot less trouble than worrying about creating one dynamically for the first submit and reusing it for subsequent submits.)

EDIT: to pass the value in the query string:

```
    $('form#ordersList').attr({
        action: "phpDump.php?orderId=" + encodeURIComponent(Order_Id),
        target: "_blank",
    }).submit();
```

You can omit [.`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) if you know the id will always be a plain number, but for user-input data you have to allow for characters that have special meaning in a URI.

Comment: This works fine. Would there be a way to do it without the hidden field? That would just submit the form with the value from `(this)` tr?

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one .line_Order_ID per TR, then you might want to structure it like this..

```
var Order_ID = $($tr + ' .line_order_ID').val();
```

That should start traversing from the TR you have, and pull the proper input value from it.

Comment: Isn't `$tr` a jQuery object? It doesn't make sense to concatenate a string with `$tr`.

Comment: No, it has to be in parentheses for that.  For example, $(tr).  The use of the $ in JavaScript is available to functions / objects / variables.

Comment: OK, let me be more explicit: the `$tr` variable defined in the question _is_ a jQuery object not because the dollar-sign magically makes it so but because it is assigned the result of a function call that returns a jQuery object. So it does not make sense to concatenate a string on the end of it.

Comment: Well, by golly, you're right.  You win.